# スクロールして要素が表示されるたびに１ずつカウントする

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

こんにちは。JS初心者なので質問させていただきます。
ワードプレスで写真家のウェブサイトを制作していて、各プロジェクトの記事には写真が複数枚あり、各プロジェクトごとに写真の合計数は変わります。
ページのデザインは、余白を使って写真をランダムにグリッドで並べるデザインです。

***＊＊＊実現したい事＊＊＊***
スクロールして写真がビューポート内に入るとカウントを１足していき、次の写真がビューポート内に入ると２と表示されていく機能を実装したいです。

記事に登録されている写真の合計数は取得できました。
そして各写真をターゲット要素にして、それぞれの要素のトップの高さも取得できましたが、この後どのようなコードを書いていいのかわからず手が止まっている状態です。。。
ロジックやご指摘、アドバイスなどをいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。！

```
<---single-post.php-->
    <?php if ($portfolioGallery) : ?>
      <div class="picture__counter">
        <div class="counter__inner">
          <span class="count">01 / </span> // ここにスクロールして要素がビューポートに入るたびに１ずつカウント足される
          <span class="total_num"> <?php echo count($portfolioGallery); ?> </span>　// 合計数を取得
          <a href="#container__top">
            <span class="arrow__top"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="project__photos">
    <?php if ($portfolioGallery) : ?>
      <?php foreach ($portfolioGallery as $index => $img) : ?>
        <?php if (in_array(($index % 10), [0, 3, 6, 9])) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="photo <?php echo 'gallery__image--' . ($index % 10) . ' ' . $size; ?>">
              <?php $size = ($img['width'] / $img['height'] > 1) ? 'about_landscape' : 'about_portrait';
              echo wp_get_attachment_image($img['ID'], $size, false, ['class' => 'gallery__image--' . ($index % 10) . ' ' . $size]);
              ?>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>



 /* main.js */

  let countTarget = $('.photo');         // ターゲット要素 
  let countNum = $('.count');            // カウント表示 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,,,, 合計数までカウントする
  let totalNum = $('.total_num').text(); // 合計数 => 13, 20, 10 etc...

  $(countTarget).each(function (index, ele) {
    let targetContentsTop = $(ele).offset().top;
    console.log(targetContentsTop); //　各要素のトップの高さも取得 -> 946.91650390625,,,

    // console.log(`index is ${index + 1}`); // 後でこのインデックス番号を変数countに追加して書き換えたい
  })
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**＊＊＊追記＊＊＊**

```
<!--html (phpなし)-->
  <div class="picture__counter">
    <div class="counter__inner">
      <span class="count"> / </span> <!--ここにカウント数を表示したい-->
        <span class="total_num"></span>　<!--各記事の写真の合計数（登録してある写真数によって変わります）-->
         <a href="#container__top">
           <span class="arrow__top"></span>
         </a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: 実装としてはPHP関係なくてJSとHTMLとCSSで実現できると思います。PHPコードを省いてHTML+JS+CSSのソースを提示していただけますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。！
WordPressを使用してサイト制作しており、写真と写真の合計数などの出力は記事データから引っ張ってきているのでPHPは必須です。PHPなしのhtmlを追記しましたのでご確認よろしくお願いします。CSSは長すぎるので省略させていただきました。JSはすでに書いてあるのでそちらをご確認いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 確かに最終的にはWordpressで実現するのでPHPは必須かもしれないですが、スクロールする度に表示しているコンテンツをカウントするはフロントエンドで解決できると思います。フロントエンドで実現してPHPに組み込めばよいかなと思います。そうすることでPHPを知らない人も回答できることになります。